# Prove that $\sum_0^\infty \frac{z^n}{1-z^{2n}}$ converges for all $\left|z\right|<1$ and $\left|z\right|>1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Question:

> Prove that $\sum_0^\infty \frac{z^n}{1-z^{2n}}$ converges for all $\left|z\right|<1$ and $\left|z\right|>1$.

Attempt:

For the case $\left|z\right|>1$, I was hoping to use the comparison test somehow against $\frac{1}{\left|z\right|^n}$ but I only got this far:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\left|z\right|}{\left|1-z^{2n}\right|} = \frac{\left|z\right|}{(1+\left|z\right|^n)(1-\left|z\right|^n)}
< \frac{\left|z\right|^n + 1}{(1+\left|z\right|^n)(1-\left|z\right|^n)}
< \frac{2}{-\left|z\right|^n}
\end{align*}

Comment: Make a case distinction between $\lvert z\rvert < 1$ and $\lvert z\rvert > 1$. In both cases, you can (for large $n$) find a majorisation by a geometric series.

Comment: what is a majorisation?

Comment: If $\lvert a_n\rvert \leqslant b_n$ for all (large enough) $n$, then $b_n$ is a majorant or majorisation of $a_n$.

Comment: @flapjackery you have a typo on the far RHS of your equation; it should be $1-|z|^n$ in the denominator, not just $-|z|^n$

Comment: @graydad thanks, I meant for it to be another inequality.

Comment: Hint: $\lvert 1-z^{2n}\rvert \geqslant \lvert z\rvert^{2n}-1$. And $$\frac{\lvert z\rvert^n}{\lvert z\rvert^{2n}-1} = \frac{\lvert z\rvert^n}{\lvert z\rvert^n+1}\cdot \frac{1}{\lvert z\rvert^n-1}.$$

Comment: Another hint: Write $z = \frac{1}{w}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks. I suspect the second hint is for Case 2, which would allow us to revert to Case 1, once I can solve it.

Comment: Or the other way round. Once you have one case, that closes the other.

Comment: @DanielFischer does your first hint follow from the reverse triangle inequality?

Comment: If you like to call it thus. I prefer to say it follows from the triangle inequality.

Comment: @flapjackery I still think it is wrong... On the far LHS you begin with a strictly positive quantity, then you proceed to find larger quantities until the far RHS you have $\frac{2}{-|z|^n}$ which is strictly negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have claimed for (for $|z|>1$) that $$\frac{\left|z\right|}{\left|1-z^{2n}\right|} = \frac{\left|z\right|}{(1+\left|z\right|^n)(1-\left|z\right|^n)}$$ however this is not true, because the quantity on the left is strictly positive while the quantity on the right is strictly negative (because $1-|z|^n$ is negative for all $|z|>1$ and $n>0$). To fix this, I believe we should have  $$\frac{\left|z\right|}{\left|1-z^{2n}\right|} = \frac{\left|z\right|}{|1+\left|z\right|^n||1-\left|z\right|^n|}$$
where now we observe that $$|1-|z|^n| = |z|^n-1 \quad \text {and} \quad |1+|z|^n|=1+|z|^n$$

so we end up with instead $$\frac{\left|z\right|}{\left|1-z^{2n}\right|} = \frac{\left|z\right|}{(1+|z|^n)(|z|^n-1)} $$

Now let's use the comparison test. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{\left|z\right|}{\left|1-z^{2(n+1)}\right|}}{\frac{\left|z\right|}{\left|1-z^{2n}\right|}}\\  =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left|1-z^{2n}\right|}{\left|1-z^{2n+2}\right|} \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1+|z|^n)(|z|^n-1)}{(1+|z|^{n+1})(|z|^{n+1}-1)} \\ < \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1+|z|^{n})(|z|^{n+1}-1)}{(1+|z|^{n+1})(|z|^{n+1}-1)} \\ =  \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1+|z|^{n}}{1+|z|^{n+1}} \\ < \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1+|z|^{n}}{|z|^{n+1}} \\= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{|z|}+ \frac{1}{|z|^{n+1}} \\ = \frac{1}{|z|} \\ <1$$

So the series converges for $|z|>1$.

For the case of $|z|<1$, your equality $$\frac{\left|z\right|}{\left|1-z^{2n}\right|} = \frac{\left|z\right|}{(1+\left|z\right|^n)(1-\left|z\right|^n)}$$ does hold because $1-|z|^n$ is always positive. If you play around with the inequalities some more you should be able to figure out how your series behaves for $|z|<1$. Someone gave the hint to use $|z|=\frac{1}{|w|}$ which is a good one. I will leave the rest to you!

Comment: thanks. why does it follow that $\frac{\left|z\right|^n+1}{(1+|z|^n)(|z|^n-1)} < \frac{2}{|z|^n}$?

Comment: graydad, thanks. But I'm still a little confused. Wouldn't the $-1$ in the denominator $|z|^n - 1$ imply that $\frac{1}{|z|^n - 1} > \frac{1}{|z|^n}$?

Comment: You are right again. I apologize for the confusion. I think we should scrap the geometric series approach and go for a comparison test. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Pretty sure I got an argument that works now. Did you have success proving convergence for $|z|<1?$

Comment: I did! Thank you very much. It was helpful to see how you deal with the modulus values.